# View my document-term matrix in R's tm library

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

I am just learning about text mining (and using R!) and would like to check I am assembling a document-term matrix correctly here. Just for two documents for now. Is this correct?

```
AAPL <- readLines('AAPL.txt')
JE<- readLines('JaneEyre.txt')

# Preliminary corpus
corpusAAPL <- Corpus(VectorSource(AAPL,JE)) %>%


# Create term-document matrices 
tdmAAPL <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpusAAPL) %>%
```

At this point I would like R to print at least a part of this TDM so I can check it is working right.

Thank you very much.

Comment: you don't need the `%>%` at the end of the lines. To view part of tdmAAPL you can use `inspect(tdm[1:10,1:10])`

Comment: Very nice, thank you. What if I have several .txt documents all in the same folder that I will want to include in the corpus. Do I need to read them all in separately? Or is there a way to make this corpus include all text docs. Thanks again for your help

Comment: `docs <- Corpus(DirSource("/path/to/text/files/))`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tm::inspect()` to view the matrix (page 15 of the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/tm.pdf)).